# Lines between nodes are not compiled in PDF output (no errors)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a truly strange problem. I wanted to construct some anabelian shapes and study the equivalence on a certain level (for my paper). I thought that outputting such simple construct with a powerful tool like `tikz` would be no problem, but I was wrong. Upon compiling the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,2.5) to[out=-60,in=-120] (1,2.5);
\draw (-1,2.5) to[out=60,in=120] (1,2.5);
\node at (-1,2.5) {$\bullet$};
\node at (1,2.5) {$\bullet$};
\node at (2,2.5) {$=$};
% Why are these not showing?
\draw (2.5,2) [out=-90,in=200] (3,3);
\draw (3,3) [out=0,in=120] (3.5,2);
\draw (3.5,2) [out=270,in=200] (2.5,2);
% Why are these not showing? 
\node at (2.5,2) {$\bullet$};
\node at (3,3) {$\bullet$};
\node at (3.5,2) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I got a strange output:

[image]

Why are the bent lines not showing up in the PDF output? It really boggles my mind, I can't find my mistake. Your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: In the three lines the `to` is missing between the start coordinate and the options: `\draw (2.5,2) to [out=-90,in=200] (3,3);`. And if the nodes should be drawn add option `draw` to it: `\node[draw] ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the action `to` missing in the code for the three bend lines. And you have to add the option `draw` to the `\node` commands if they should be drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-1,2.5) to[out=-60,in=-120] (1,2.5);
    \draw (-1,2.5) to[out=60,in=120] (1,2.5);
    \node at (-1,2.5) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (1,2.5) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (2,2.5) {$=$};
    % 
    \draw (2.5,2) to[out=-90,in=200] (3,3);
    \draw (3,3) to[out=0,in=120] (3.5,2);
    \draw (3.5,2) to[out=270,in=200] (2.5,2);
    %
    \node[draw] at (2.5,2) {$\bullet$};
    \node[draw] at (3,3) {$\bullet$};
    \node[draw] at (3.5,2) {$\bullet$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you should change the values for `out` and `in` a bit.